# Place div.innerHTML as a hidden form value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a long page with identical section I am attempting to combine into one that has:

TITLE
description
form

I have working mouseovers that change the title and description, but need a solution to change the value of a hidden form input to the new titles when changed.

**HOW do I get the hidden form value to change onmouseover to equal current TITLE.value?**

```
<a href="." onmouseover="changeContent('title', 'Title/Value'); changeContent('body', 'DESCRIPTION')">Milestones</a>
```

PHP

```
function changeContent(id, msg) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (id) {
         el.innerHTML = msg;
    }
}
```

FORM

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="category" />
```

Comment: input value = Title. When title is changed on mouseover href then so does hidden form input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
document.getElementById('hiddenInputId').value = msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hidden element doesn't have an Id, so you can use following:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName('category');
elems[0].value = <<new value>>
```

`getElementsByName` always returns an array so you have to pickup first element and set its value.

Cheers !!